# Union type assignment in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to make an assignment like this to work?

```
type A = { a: string };
type B = { b: string };

const x = {
  AA: undefined as A | undefined,
  BB: undefined as B | undefined,
}

const name1 = "AA"
const x1 = x[name1]; // type: A | undefined
x[name1] = x1;

const name2 = "AA" as "AA"|"BB";
const x2 = x[name2]; // type: A | B | undefined
x[name2] = x2; //ERROR

//Type 'A | B | undefined' is not assignable to type '(A & B) | undefined'.
//  Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'A & B'.
//    Property 'b' is missing in type 'A' but required in type 'B'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a recent [breaking change](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types) introduced in TypeScript 3.5 (see the [relevant pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) for more info) which improved the soundness when writing to [indexed-access/lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).  In short, what you are doing is only safe since you happen to know for a fact that you are writing a value back into the property it was just read from.  But the compiler doesn't realize this since you intentionally widened the type of the property key to a union.  The type of `x2` is therefore `A | B | undefined`, and it isn't safe to write that type back to `x[name2]`:

```
const name2 = "AA" as "AA" | "BB";
let x2 = x[name2]; // type: A | B | undefined
x2 = { b: "okay" }; // works because x2 is of A | B | undefined
x[name2] = x2; // now this error makes sense, right?
```

The problem here, as I see it, is a lack of support in the language for what I've been calling ["correlated types"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  You know that the two union-typed expressions `x2` and `x[name2]` of type `A | B | undefined` are not independent of each other.  Either they are both `A | undefined`, or they are both `B | undefined`.  But the compiler has no way to express that dependence in general.  Workarounds here generally involve generics, type assertions, or code duplication.

---

Generics: One way to make the compiler understand this to be safe is to abstract what you are doing to a generic function where name is of a generic type that extends `"AA" | "BB"`:

```
function genericVersion<N extends "AA" | "BB">(name: N) {
  const x3 = x[name];
  x[name] = x3; // no error
}
genericVersion("AA" as "AA" | "BB");
```

This works because the compiler allows you to assign a value of type `T[N]` to a variable of type `T[N]` when `N` is a generic parameter.  It's still [technically unsafe](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559):

```
function unsafeGeneric<N extends "AA" | "BB">(readName: N, writeName: N) {
  const x4 = x[readName];
  x[writeName] = x4; // no error
}
unsafeGeneric("AA", "BB"); // no error... oops
```

but it's more useful to allow this than it is to disallow it.

---

Assertions: Another workaround is to loosen the type of `x` for the assignment via a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), as in:

```
type Loosen<T extends object, K extends keyof T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? T[K] : T[P]
};

(x as Loosen<typeof x, typeof name2>)[name2] = x2; // okay
```

The type `Loosen<T, K>` takes an object type `T` and a set of its keys `K` and returns a wider type where any of the property types in `T` with keys in `K` can be assigned to any.  For example,

```
type L = Loosen<{ a: string; b: number; c: boolean }, "b" | "c">;
```

is equivalent to

```
type L = {
    a: string;
    b: number | boolean;
    c: number | boolean;
}
```

And thus I can write a `boolean` to `b` amd a `number` to `c` without complaint if I widen a value of type `{ a: string; b: number; c: boolean }` to `L` before the assignment.  When you do assertions like this you need to be careful not to lie to the compiler, and put the wrong value in the wrong property.

---

Duplication: The last workaround would be to manually walk the compiler through all the possibilities... this is fully type safe but redundant:

```
const name5 = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "AA" : "BB";
if (name5 === "AA") {
  const x5 = x[name5];
  x[name5] = x5; // okay
} else {
  const x5 = x[name5];
  x[name5] = x5; // okay
}
```

---

I'm afraid I don't have a wonderful answer for you.  The improved soundness in TS3.5 is 100% correct and does catch bugs, but has also caused a lot of headaches for developers.  Usually I tend to go with a type assertion as it's often the least disruptive change that achieves the goal.

Oh well.  Hope that helps!  Good luck.

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKBnYAnAlgHYDmUAvgNwCwAUKJFAEILJQBGmOBJ51NtAYwD2hHFAAeLJLSiwYmAK6EAJhABmRCMrRZYUAD5QlqjYS0AaGU0aKV6zdtS7mh4-bPLalWoJFjCqAC2EACMLABEMDDhfMKiwBJhiOIA2gHBIQC6fKnpoZks4iF8vvFQeQBMEVHhOlCR0Qb1jIwxtAA2EAniVclpQRAV2VAA9CNQAgAWqCRaUMBCUJ3AtD1S7JjhQkJgWPgQtZSj45C4ahACwO0gUABuqO34njS5A0OFFRTHUBC4uEK4Hw0MbjABi+HEmAA4hAzAQBFggWolJd8CIoMRYb98AIAGq-PYiAA8ADkfuJgLDlLoGrVDOEWuEAHwACjymBJAEpkFY4mJxABmQr9YLZKyvUWFAVfMblRa-f6AmhkWiYuE4-G4QmEFm0up6+mMzklGjIwio9FKLCoc4w9UCUnkykqGk1JoM1qs3AQVDKEkDDnmKAAdwIlP9wQ53OkNFkfO6ABZhd7fRGIGLYxIUqH8OGBgVkgmZeNCPK-gCvLQrTaIHbsQJdTUgx7wsbvqWfuXcAA6XtQba7IEgqDgyGwLBYX7ANGEIH0aAAGW2k8IRIAKk6qbohGwAFYXYBBgDSm5dUAA1hAQEI1FA10ypFYUgAFKBEC9Xm93zKYV8QClblAJ4APx3ikR4FJga4vpkXgmiykhOFAS5CCuRLzl+4hBhht6VEynIioMBYSJ8Q6yqOmAACIKGAjwCKg04iEC8blAMACsLAALIMZM3a4DMyhCIELLckSUAAAzdhxoF6psjJ8Pgt5suxCDwIgtLRryfjdBxfR5GxGayBKEAGYUbF8GQPztJOPKZix4i6Vm+mGU57HEQ5Fm0EAA)